# Why aren't armored huskies showing up after installation of Dawnguard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

In the Skyrim Dawnguard DLC expansion pack, there are supposed to be armored huskies and armored trolls as new companions, but when I look in the pen for the trolls and huskies, I only see the trolls.

I have completed the Dawnguard quest line and they still aren't there. Does anybody know how to fix this, where they are (right of the troll pen but they may be somewhere else so I've heard), or if I have to do anything else before I get these huskies?

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though [there is a bug that causes huskies not to spawn](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Husky), although details are scant. You've probably run afoul of it.

The two huskies that are suitable for recruitment as followers are [Bran](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bran) and [Sceolang](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sceolang). They should both be in the pen in the Fort Dawnguard caves. If you are playing on the PC, you could try to summon them to you using the console: `Prid <refid>` and then `moveto player` (the refid's for both pets are `xx01AA7B` and `xx01AA7C`; note that the first two hex digits will vary based on the DLC you have installed).

Alternatively, you could try to spawn them using `player.placeatme <refid>`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you are looking for the huskies you are looking in the right spot. They do not share the same pen as the trolls. The huskies are found at the other end of the fort, in the same general area where Beleval and Ingjard will eventually be doing crossbow and two handed practice during the day.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work and/or don't want to cheat, get both the Unofficial Skyrim patch (http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19/?) and the Unofficial Dawnguard patch (http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23491/?). There also is an Unofficial Dragonborn patch (http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31083/?) and an Unofficial Hearthfire patch (http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25127/?).